# Null reference for my Model in the builder (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an interface for a ViewModel:

```
 public interface IViewModelBuilder<T>
    {

        T Build(SessionState stateData, Dictionary<string, object> args = null);
    }
```

and I have a builder that implements that Interface :

```
  public class RepairBuilder : IViewModelBuilder<RepairModel>
{
    public RepairModel Build(SessionState stateData, Dictionary<string, object> args = null)
    {
        //var T= new Dictionary<string, object> { { "vehicleid", vehicleid } };
        var claimCondition = stateData.Claim.GetClaimCondition();

        var repairModel = new RepairModel
        {
            RepairState = ClaimRules.GetRepairState(stateData.Claim, stateData.CurrentInterestedParty, claimCondition),
            Status = EstimateStatus.EstimateOk,
            Appointment = ClaimRules.GetActiveRelatedAppointment(stateData.Claim, stateData.CurrentInterestedParty),
            DaysToRepairs = string.Format(
                             "{0} {1}",
                             stateData.CurrentInterestedParty.Vehicle.Repair.DaysToRepair,
                             stateData.CurrentInterestedParty.Vehicle.Repair.DaysToRepair == 1 ? "Day" : "Days"),
            GrossTotalAmount = stateData.CurrentInterestedParty.Vehicle.Repair.GrossTotalAmount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
           //TODO add estimate document logic
        };

        return repairModel;
    }
```

so at the line var MyModel the model is empty and its throwing an exception.

should I initialize the dictionnary before .if yes how we do it?

My code was running before adding the dictionnary in the interface parameter.

and my controller is using the builder like that:

```
    public class RepairsController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IViewModelBuilder<RepairModel> _repairBuilder;

    public RepairsController(IViewModelBuilder<RepairModel> repairBuilder, ISessionState stateData, IHttpRequestHelper httpRequest)
        : base(stateData,httpRequest)
    {
        this._repairBuilder = repairBuilder;

    }


 public ActionResult Estimate(string claimNumber, string vehicleid)
    {

        var repairStateModel = this._repairBuilder.Build(this.StateData,new Dictionary<string, object>{{"vehicleid",vehicleid}});
        return this.View("Estimate", repairStateModel);
    }
 }
```

Comment: What exception is it throwing? Can you post the whole Build method?

Comment: What Exception ? and which function is thowing the exception ? since `var MyModel` is present in both Build and Estimate.
It could be helpfull too if you post the complete instanciation at `new MyModel(){...}`.

Comment: I edited my post and the model in the builder file is throwing null exception.Its null